# Using newline in Cordova iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, encoding

I have an app built with Cordova and at some point I display a string with a newline escape character (`\n`) somewhere in the string. Then If I build the app and test it on both an Android and iOS device, the line break shows up on the Android device but the not on the iOS device.

Is there an encoding issue that I'm missing or something?

The string: `'Some Text: \n www.somesite.com'`